# Image not display on UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angularjs 1.6 and angular-material 1.1.5 and we are work on angular component base.

I want to set image and it's src is from project folder.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div layout="row">
  <div flex>
    <md-toolbar class="md-tall">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        **<img width="40" alt="image" src="../img/logo.png" style="max-height: 73.0px; width: 40px;">**
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
  </div>
  <div flex="30">
    <md-toolbar class="md-tall">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button class="md-raised md-warn">Sign Up</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-warn">Sign In</md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it's give me error on browser (http://localhost:9999/app/images/logo.png 404 (Not Found).

Can you please give me any solution?

**Folder Structure**

[image]

Comment: Please check your image path is correct.I think you need to remove ../ from image path '../img/logo.png' to 'img/logo.png'

Comment: show your folder structure

Comment: Are you using any kind of JS builder ? Grunt/Gulp etc ?

Comment: No, I am use webpack